# CVS - grabbing only the latest change

Tags: cvs

foo.C  has been updated 5 times since the tag I checked out.  I want to only grab the very last change made to foo - how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'cvs -q update foo.c' gets the latest version

'cvs -n -q update' shows the diff from local against remote.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want the latest version. I want only the latest change. so I'm at 1.0 which was tagged.  HEAD is at 1.5. I only want the change from 1.4 to 1.5 as 1.0 to 1.1-1.4 were big changes I can't build with.

Comment: I could not follow what you wrote above w.r.t version you wanted - all you have to do is add version to the cvs update command. If you need the syntax see http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/cvsmanual/updateoptions.html